# python numpy threshhold specific values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an RGB image as a HxWxC numpy array and I want to reduce it to an HxW numpy array where all the entries are 0 if the color isn't an exact RGB value and 255 if it is an exact RGB value, I am currently doing this:

```
im2 = (im[..., 2] == 255) * (im[..., 0] == 0) * (im[..., 1] == 0) * numpy.uint8(255)
```

This code sets all pixels that are not (0, 0, 255) to 0, and (0, 0, 255) to 255. But I imagine there must be a neater and more compact way to do that. Is there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.ndarray.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) along the last axis:

```
>>> x = np.array([[[255,0,0], [0,255,0], [0,0,255]],
                [[1,12,255], [23,45,22], [0,0,0]],
                [[0,0,255],[1,2,3], [255,234,232]]])
>>> x
array([[[255,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255]],

       [[  1,  12, 255],
        [ 23,  45,  22],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0, 255],
        [  1,   2,   3],
        [255, 234, 232]]])

>>> np.where((x == [0,0,255]).all(axis=-1), 255, 0)
array([[  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [255,   0,   0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to check if your colors match your exact RGB and multiply is by 255 (the trick is when you multiply `False` by number it outputs 0 and if you multiply `True` by any number, it acts like 1). `[None,None,:]` adds the dimensions for correct broadcasting. `all(-1)` checks to see if `all` three RGB colors match:

```
#the color you wish to match
rgb = np.array([0,0,255])
#the output you want
(im==rgb[None,None,:]).all(-1)*numpy.uint8(255)
```